# Matrix algebra on a rolling subset of data in R

Tags: r, matrix

I am a novice to R and have the following problem:

**Data Input**:

I have a CSV with two columns like this:

```
1,10
2,20
3,30
4,40
5,50
...
N, M
```

**Problem:**

```
a) Read in the CSV
b) Convert to a matrix
c) Take 4 rows starting with the first row
d) calculate the third column of elements as a simple square of the second column elements
e) Calculate the sumproduct (value11*value12*value13 + value21*value22*value23 + value31*value32*value33 +value41*value42*value43)
f) Do this until the end of the dataset
```

Outcome:

The result for the first two matrices should be as follows:

**First matrix:**

Start with the first row, select four rows.

Step 1

```
1,10
2,20
3,30
4,40
```

Step 2 (add the 3rd column as a square of the second column value)

```
1,10,100
2,20,400
3,30,900
4,40,1600
```

Step 3 (calculate the sumproduct)
    (1*10*100 + 2*20*400 +3*30*900 + 4*40*1600) == 354.000

**Second matrix:**

Proceed with the second row and take the next 4 rows

Step 1

```
2,20
3,30
4,40
5,50
```

Step 2 (add the 3rd column as a square of the second column value)

```
2,20,400
3,30,900
4,40,1600
5,50,2500
```

Step 3 (calculate the sumproduct)

```
(2*20*400 +3*30*900 + 4*40*1600 + 5*50*2500) == 978.000
```

**N matrix**
Do steps 1 to 3 until the end of the dataset

**RESULT**

The result should be the list of sumproducts:

```
354.000, 978.000, ..., N
```

Thank you!

Comment: I do not believe that you are unable to solve at least some checkpoints in your problem description by doing some research, eg. reading basic introductions and tutorials.

Comment: Hi Roland, I solved some of the checkpoints. My problem is how to define the four row chunks of the data as a matrix and do it until the end of the dataset. I event managed to do it with a For loop but I think there should be a better way to do it as a simple loop.

Comment: You're close. Think about how you would subset your rows based on an index. You can probably do this in a number of ways, but a `for` loops would be one intuitive approach.